# Maps API release key not working

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps, keytool

I just finished my first app which uses the Maps API and a Maps Fragment.
Everything works fine with the debugging so I decided to make a signed apk.
To get the signed apk to work with the Maps API I need the new Key. Here is how I tried it:

1) Generate signed apk

2) I create a new keystore file with the ending .jks

3) The apk is succesfully created   (this apk doesn't contain the new key yet)

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:compileReleaseJava
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:compileReleaseNdk
:app:preDexRelease
:app:dexRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease
:app:zipalignRelease
:app:assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 57.752 secs
```

4) I use the keytool and receive the sha1 from the .jks keystore file

5) I go to the API website and generate a new key for the same project as the one i entered the debug key

6) I get a key

6.1)Odd, it just says "Key for Android applications" not "Key for Android applications (with certificate)" as it is written in the documentation for Maps API

7) I put the new key into the field where the debug key used to sit

8) I once again generate a signed apk (with entering the password for the keystore and alias)

8.1) same log output, no abnormalities

9) I install the apk on a device

10) The map tiles don't load

I have read the documentation again and again, but i can't find where i am doing a mistake

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the SHA1 from your keystore into the the list of allowed apps for your project in the API console.

From the google APIs console webpage select your project in the drop down menu. Then click API Access. From there, you should be a button that says "Edit Allowed Android apps." Click that, and you'll see some instructions on what to do.

Comment: Thank you,but that's what I already did in step 5 and 6. I have tried generating a new key for the SHA1 and I have tried adding the SHA1 to the list of allowed apps as you just described, from the key that works with the debug version.

Comment: Have you added the new key to the AndroidManifest?

Comment: I found out what was causing the error. In automatically created maps activity from Android Studio the Key was imported into the manifest from a resource file "values/google_maps_api.xml". When i replaced it there I supppose for some reason it didn't get imported into the release builds. I now hardcoded my key into the manifest and now it works :-)        thanks a lot for your assistance